# How to check if String ends with String

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Complete the solution so that it returns true if the first argument (string) passed in ends with the 2nd argument (also a string).

Examples:

Solution ('abc', 'bc') // returns true,
solution ('abc', 'd') // returns false
Create a function that does this.

My code is:

```js
function solution(str, ending){
 return (str.split('').filter(str => str.length > str.length - 2).join('')) == ending ? "true" : "false"
 
 
}
```

The error I get:

```js
expected 'false' to equal true
```

Comment: That's a complicated effort when there is just [endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith). Any reason why you don't use that method?

Comment: How about using endsWith?
str.endsWith(ending)

Comment: no particular reason just wanted to see if i could use this way or if a few tweaks can be done so that it can work

Comment: What do you think `str.length > str.length - 2` does? Do you see **any** possibility for that expression to be false? And why 2? What is the relevance of 2 in this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement String.endsWith() without using built-in method .endsWith() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026898/how-to-implement-string-endswith-without-using-built-in-method-endswith-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- You have used the name `str` for the function parameter **and** for the parameter in the `filter` callback function. So in that callback function you'll have no access to the original `str` value.
- In the `filter` callback, `str` will be a **single** character, so its length will always be 1. It makes no sense to compare it with anything
- If you go with `filter`, then you'd want to do something with the *index* of the character, not the character itself.
- In this problem the value 2 has no special meaning, it should not need to occur anywhere in your code
- The function returns a string "true" or "false", but you are required to return a boolean value (`true` or `false`). Those are not strings.
- Using the conditional (ternary) operator just to return a boolean is overkill: just return the boolean expression that serves for the condition.
- The whole idea of using `filter` is not necessary as there is [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

I guess you wanted to do something like this:

```js
function solution(str, ending){
  return str.split('').filter((_, i) => i >= str.length - ending.length).join('') == ending ? true : false;
}

console.log(solution("longword", "word"));
```

But it can be as simple as:

```js
function solution(str, ending){
  return str.endsWith(ending);
}

console.log(solution("longword", "word"));
```

Comment: please elaborate on this part   .filter ((_, i) => i >= str.length - ending.length)

Comment: and also is this the best practice?

Comment: `i` is the index of the current visited character in the loop, and `str.length - ending.length` is the number of characters that should be *excluded*. So if the current index has passed over the number of characters to exclude, the expression will return true, and so `filter` will *include* that character.

Comment: This was what I *guessed* you tried to do. And no, this is not best practice. The advised way is `endsWith`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
function solution(str, ending){
  var a = str.slice(-3);
  var b = ending;
  if (a === b){
    return true;
  }
  
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).